# Unity 5 - Best way to make character interact with objects in scene

Tags: 2d, unity-game-engine

Am deploying a 2D RPG game, am trying to figure out the best way to make the character interact with an object in the scene (screen for example) when the character stands infront of the screen and presses X for example.

Am using unity 5.3

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by [checking this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/634717/how-can-i-raycast-the-direction-my-2d-character-is.html)

For those who check this and still didnt get it, contact me and ill help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have an OntriggerEnter set a bool to true, then in update check if player pressed x, if they did check if they can interact with item, if so do thing that you want them to do. So the player can't interact away from the screen have on trigger exit set the bool back to false. For this to work you will need to have a trigger on the object you wish to interact with.

(My preferred way but a little more complicated) Another way is using a raycast from a player to the object and if the player is with the set distance allow them to interact with the scene.

Comment: I solved it by getting character positions from GetAxis, then casted a ray towards the direction am facing ignoring all layers except the layer i wanted.

Comment: You can also use Transform.Forward in your raycast check, that way you don't have to check the Axis. because most 2D characters scale in negative x when they face left, making the x direction always facing forward. Glad you solved it.